# Git has a Problem with the SSL CA cert on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, git

I am trying to clone a repository from bitbucket.org to my Raspberry Pi using

```
git clone https://MyName@bitbucket.org/MyName/mygit.git
```

Git outputs the following, if i add `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` in front of it:

```
Cloning into 'mygit'...
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to bitbucket.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 2401:1d80:1010::150...
* 0x1614658 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x161cfc0; (connection #0)
* Connected to bitbucket.org (2401:1d80:1010::150) port 443 (#0)
* Connected to bitbucket.org (2401:1d80:1010::150) port 443 (#0)
* error reading ca cert file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt (Base64 unexpected header error.)
* Closing connection #0
* Expire cleared
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to bitbucket.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 2401:1d80:1010::150...
* 0x1614658 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x161cfc0; (connection #0)
* Connected to bitbucket.org (2401:1d80:1010::150) port 443 (#0)
* Connected to bitbucket.org (2401:1d80:1010::150) port 443 (#0)
* error reading ca cert file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt (Base64 unexpected header error.)
* Closing connection #0
* Expire cleared
error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) while accessing https://MyName@bitbucket.org/MyName/mygit.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `ca-certificates.crt` file for corruption.  You shouldn't get the `Base64` error message:

```
error reading ca cert file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt (Base64 unexpected header error.)
```

You may need to install the `ca-certificates` package and run `sudo update-ca-certificates` which creates a new `/etc/ssh/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file.

Answer (score 2):

Running update-ca-certificates was not enough in my case... I had to force the ca-certificates package to reinstall, and then run update-ca-certificates in order to make it work.

Here's what worked for me...

1. Reinstall ca-certificates

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates --reinstall
```

2- Update the CA certificate list

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's the difference to the other answer given two years before?

Comment: Running update-ca-certificates was not enough in my case...  I had to force the ca-certificates package to reinstall, and then run update-ca-certificates in order to make it work.  HTH

Comment: Can you please add the information to the answer? You can edit it. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.